# Executing a stored procedure asynchronously without awaiting it and blocking the UI

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asynchronous, async-await

I have several stored procedures that INSERT or UPDATE into the database in my ASP.NET web forms application. I want these queries to execute, but I don't want the user's UI or page execution to await them finishing. They don't take very long (much less than a second), but that's a second that the user has to wait for the page load.

I'm typically looking at inserting logging or history into a table. The user's page view isn't dependent on the execution or results of the query.

I'm trying to use .NET's async methods, like ExecuteNonQueryAsync(). But I think I've got this wrong conceptually. ExecuteNonQueryAsync() seems to be for running two or more longer-running database operations in parallel, and blocking the UI until both are complete.

```
private async Task<string> DoTransaction()
{
    string value = "";

    using (SqlConnection objCS = DB.AdminNET())
    {
        await objCS.OpenAsync();
        using (SqlTransaction t = objCS.BeginTransaction())
        using (SqlCommand objCommand = new SqlCommand("WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'; EXEC logtiming @line", objCS, t))
        {
            try
            {
                objCommand.Parameters.Add("@line", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "log me";
                await objCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
            catch
            {
                t.Rollback();
                throw;
            }

            t.Commit();

            value = "done";
        }
    }

    return value;
}

protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await DoTransaction(g);
}
```

This code will insert my test data after the introduced delay. However, it holds the whole page response to the user until the delay is over. Ideally, I would want the page to return to the user immediately and then five seconds later I'd see my results in the table. Is ExecuteNonQueryAsync() the wrong tool for this? Or is there some change I can make that I haven't found yet, eg. "not await"?

Comment: And for a non-proper way, you can fire off a new thread and let it run by itself to completion.

Comment: Any back end code renders the whole page and returns it so you won't be seeing any 'late updates' to your page in this way. The way this has been solved for years is through AJAX - do some investigation in that area.

Answer (score 6):

> ExecuteNonQueryAsync() seems to be... blocking the UI until both are complete.

Yes, this is how ASP.NET works. All other HTTP servers such as ASP.NET Core and Node.js work the same way: there is only one response to send, and it is sent only when the request handler has completed - this is true whether the handler is synchronous or asynchronous.

For more information see my [article on async ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx); relevant section:

> Asynchronous Code Is Not a Silver Bullet
>
> As wonderful as asynchronous request handling is, it won’t solve all your problems. There are a few common misunderstandings around what async and await can do on ASP.NET.
>
> When some developers learn about async and await, they believe it’s a way for the server code to “yield” to the client (for example, the browser). However, async and await on ASP.NET only “yield” to the ASP.NET runtime; the HTTP protocol remains unchanged, and you still have only one response per request. If you needed SignalR or AJAX or UpdatePanel before async/await, you’ll still need SignalR or AJAX or UpdatePanel after async/await.

The proper way to solve this is to have a [reliable queue with an independent background processing application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/dn589781(v=pandp.10)). Your web request handler only places an item in the queue and returns to your client quickly. Then, the background app processes that queue and does the actual database changes.